# Object Particles not rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

As the title says, I'm having a hard time rendering my particles in cycle (but they do appear in Eevee and viewport)

I checked the layer, the items visibility in render, the cameray ray, the emitter checkbox in the particle settings, and by all intent and purpose I think they should render?
But they don't, so I obviously missed some setting, and I'm now pulling the "help me" card

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b0sh0ppfl08s7mk/WIP.blend?dl=0

Can anyone tell me what I've missed, please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use ***Emitter*** particles for your static particle crystals ("sprinkles"). For static particles that don't change their position like grass, trees, sprinkles, sesame seeds on a burger, ... it's better to use ***Hair*** particles. They are static and always dead.

Emitter particles are used for animation mainly. For birds, fishes, moths, dust, and fluid. They have a lifetime and die.

Looks like you knew that and have made the settings accordingly: Only 1 frame animation and set *Frame Start* and *End* to 1, lifetime 1. Unfortunately, it does not work because in frame 1 the particles are still unborn and not rendered by default. The nasty thing is that you see them in the viewport.

Possible fixes:

- use particle type *Hair*. You need to apply the scale of the instance object and scale it up a bit. For some reason, the particles are smaller when rendered as *Hair*.
- or set *Frame Start* and *End* to 0
- or tick the checkbox *Render > Extras > Unborn* in particle settings
- or render frame 2 and tick the checkbox *Render > Extras > Dead* in particle settings
- or use particle type *Hair* ;-)

Comment: OMG thank you! That's going to be useful for so much more than this file too!!!